# Special characters as Java constants

Tags: java, char, symbols

Is it possible to create a char constant in Java for special characters? Dragging the character into the code editor window doesn't seem to work.

In the Mac character palette, if I use the "copy character info" command on the "Clubs" card suit symbol, for example, it puts this on the clipboard: 
Unicode: U+2663 U+FE0F, UTF-8: E2 99 A3 EF B8 8F

Is is possible to use this somehow in a statement like:

```
public final char CLUB_SYMBOL = (?);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [unicode escape syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html):

```
public final String CLUB_SYMBOL = "\u2663\ufe0f";
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the other "U+FE0F" for?

Comment: That part is a unicode variation selector. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_Selectors_(Unicode_block)) for more info.

Comment: Which means `final String CLUB_SYMBOL = "\u2663\ufe0f"` might be more appropriate.